# How to setText in a textArea from an ArrayList?

Tags: arraylist, textarea, javafx-2

I have an ArrayList `ArrayList<String> externalDataList = new ArrayList<>(1600);`and I would like to display in a textArea first 3 strings, but I can't succed:

Here is my code

```
textareaShowPreview.setPrefRowCount(3);

Iterator<String> it = externalDataList.iterator();
       int tot = 0;
       while(it.hasNext() && tot<3){
           String element = it.next();
           textareaShowPreview.setText(element + "\n");
           System.out.println("elements are: " + element);
           tot++;
       }
```

The sout correctly print first 3 strings

```
element are: 23/05/2007 ,30.9455,31.2545,30.9091,30.9545,7518142
element are: 24/05/2007 ,30.6545,31.0909,30.5364,30.6909,12851606
element are: 25/05/2007 ,30.6636,30.8545,30.4818,30.8091,9392088
```

but in textArea I have only first one

[image]

How do I have to modify my code to show in textArea all three strings, one string per row?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use appendText instead of setText [here is a link](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#appendText%28java.lang.String%29).

The setText, delete the previous text and set the text you are giving to it. The append keep the current text in your text area.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, Antonio!