# How to display text on several lines in TextArea

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I tested this code to display strings on several lines:

```
TextArea dataPane = new TextArea();
        dataPane.setEditable(false);
        dataPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(hbox.widthProperty());

        dataPane.setWrapText(true);     // New line of the text exceeds the text area
        dataPane.setPrefRowCount(10);
        dataPane.setText("Testdata");
        dataPane.setText("\ndata");
```

But as a result I get only the String `data`. What is the proper way to display strings on several lines in JavaFX?

Comment: setText("Testdata\ndata"). you have just overwritten the existing text.

Comment: Take a look on this, it's the same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103275/how-to-settext-in-a-textarea-from-an-arraylist/17103797#17103797

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [TextArea.appendText](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#appendText-java.lang.String-)

```
TextArea dataPane = new TextArea();
        dataPane.setEditable(false);
        dataPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(hbox.widthProperty());

        dataPane.setWrapText(true);     // New line of the text exceeds the text area
        dataPane.setPrefRowCount(10);
        dataPane.setText("Testdata");
        dataPane.appendText("\ndata");
```